# Animating the closing of a Jquery UI dialog by reducing its size and moving it relative to another element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have a Jquery UI dialog and I close it by having it sized to zero and moving its position as in:

```
  $('#myDialog').dialog({
  ...
  beforeClose: function() {
      $("#myDialog").dialog("widget").animate({ 
          'position': 'absolute',
          'left': '1250px',
          'top': '20px',
          'height': '0px',
          'width': '0px'
      }, 600);
  },
  ...
```

This works fine but not if the window is resized because the goal is to have it move towards another element. I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
  beforeClose: function() {
      $("#myDialog").dialog("widget")
          .animate({'height': '0px','width': '0px'},400)
          .animate({'position': { my: "right top", at:"left bottom", 
                     of: "#myButton" }},400);
  },
```

This does resize the dialog to zero but the positioning does not work at all.
Can you suggest any way to do this?